# OpenGL object no lighting

Tags: python, opengl, buffer, light, normals

I can't get my model to light properly. I am making an object consisting of little cubes/voxels and all sides have the same light intensity. I am writing my code in Python and use numpy for arrays. My points array is a flat/1D array of triangle corner points. My normals array is a flat/1D array of normal 3d-vectors for each triangle.

The following code is in an init procedure:

```
# ===============================================
# First add points to buffer
# ===============================================
points = numpy.array(points,dtype=numpy.float32)
points=points * scale
self.voxelPtBufferLen = len(points) // 3

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
self.voxelPtBufferIdx = glGenBuffers(1)
dataSizePt = arrays.ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount(points)

# print ("datasize",dataSize)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.voxelPtBufferIdx)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSizePt, points, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

# ===============================================
# Second add normals for each triangle to buffer
# ===============================================
normals = numpy.array(normals, dtype=numpy.float32)
self.voxelNmBufferLen = len(normals)

glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
self.voxelNmBufferIdx = glGenBuffers(1)
dataSizeNm = arrays.ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount(normals)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.voxelNmBufferIdx)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSizeNm, normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
```

And then to draw this I have the following code

```
colorFront = (0.1, 0.3, 0.6)
colorBack = (1, 0.3, 0.3)
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, (0.2, 0.2, 0.2))
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, (0.8, 0.8, 1.0))
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 50.0)

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE)


glLight(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, (0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 1))
glLight(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, (0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 1))
glLight(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, (0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 1))
glLight(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, (10,10,10))
glLight(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, (-10,-10,-10))
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1)

glBegin(GL_QUADS)
glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0)
glVertex3f(10, 10, 10)
glVertex3f(12, 12, 12)
glVertex3f(10, 12, 12)
glVertex3f(12, 10, 12)
glEnd()

glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)
glColor3fv(colorFront)

# DRAW VOXELS
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.voxelPtBufferIdx)
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,None)

glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.voxelNmBufferIdx)
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, self.voxelPtBufferLen)

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major issue is that you have to enable lighting by. See [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml):

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
```

When lighting is enabled, then the colors of the mesh are determined by the material paramters ([`glMaterial`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMaterial.xml)). See also [Basic OpenGL Lighting](https://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/opengl_lighting.html).

You don't set the ambient material parameter (`GL_AMBIENT`) and the diffuse material parameter (`GL_DIFFUSE`) seems to be to weak. Try something like:

```
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, (0.3, 0.3, 0.3))
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, (1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
```